# Got tag name, but no values while parsing with miniXML

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing

Why this code rettrievs only tags, but not values?

```
int fromString(char* str)
{
    mxml_node_t *root, *node;   
    root  = mxmlLoadString(NULL,str, MXML_TEXT_CALLBACK);
    node = root;
    const char *textValue;
    char  bbb [256];
    const char *name;
    int aaa;
    mxmlGetElement(node);

    if (!strcmp(mxmlGetElement(node),"Root" ))
        {
        node = mxmlGetFirstChild(node);

        while (name= mxmlGetElement(node))
            {
            if (!strcmp(name,"AAA" ))
                {
                    cout<<"getting AAA"<<endl; 
                    aaa= mxmlGetInteger(node);
                    cout<<aaa<<std::endl;
                } else
            if (!strcmp(name,"BBB" ))
                {
                    cout<<"getting BBB"<<endl;
                    textValue=mxmlGetText(node,0);
                    if (textValue!=NULL) 
                        {
                        strcpy(bbb,textValue);
                        cout<<textValue<<std::endl;
                        }
                }
            node = mxmlGetNextSibling(node);
            }
        return 0;
        } else return -1;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    fromString("<Root><AAA>12</AAA><BBB>txt</BBB></Root>");

    int i ;

    cin>>i;
}
```

Output:

```
getting AAA
0
getting BBB
```

Answer (score 0):

In the XML snippet you show:

```
<Root>
 <AAA>12</AAA>
 <BBB>txt</BBB>
</Root>
```

I'm pretty sure that the `12` is a separate integer node that is a child of the `AAA` node. So you would have to iterate over that node's children, to find the contained integer(s).

See the [initial node structure example](http://www.msweet.org/documentation/project3/Mini-XML.html#3_2) in the documentation.

Comment: I tried to extract one more node from AAA one, but this didn't helped: cnode = mxmlGetFirstChild(node);
     cout<<"getting AAA"<<endl; 
     aaa= mxmlGetInteger(cnode);